# Which is wrong? Java, Maths or Me...?? Confused...!

Tags: java, expression, arithmetic-expressions

I've the below SOP:

```
System.out.println(9 - ((9 / 2) * 2));
```

From the maths that I learnt in school, it should evaluate to `0`.

But I'm getting the output as `1`...!!!

I've tried evaluating the same expression in Google the output is `0`.

Java evaluates to 1 while according to Maths, it is evaluated to 0. Any explanation?

Comment: Java and Math can't be wrong. It's you my friend.

Comment: 9/2....integer/integer which will give u 4...so i guess Java gave the correct o/p

Comment: welcome to programming

Comment: And even the other assumption is wrong here: Java doesn’t “evaluate to 1”; if you analyse the compiled class file you will find, that the answer “1” is already given by the compiler, Java doesn’t do any math evaluation here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're victim of integer division !

> Dividing integers in a computer program requires special care. Some
>   programming languages, treat integer division (i.e by giving the
>   integer quotient as the answer). So the answer is an integer.

Some logic :

In Java :

```
9/2 = 4 
4*2 = 8
9-8 = 1
```

In real life :

```
9/2 = 4.5
4.5*2 = 9
9-9 = 0
```

To avoid that you can cast one of the argument to double in your division :

```
System.out.println(9 - (((double)9 / 2) * 2));
```

Comment: The rest die because they used `==` instead of `equals`.

Answer (score 1):

Integer division is the culprit here. `(9/2)` gives `4`. And therefore, `(9 - (4 * 2))` would evaluate to `1`.

*Step-by-step:*

```
(9 - ((9 / 2) * 2));
(9 - ((4) * 2)); // integer division
(9 - (8));
1 // final result
```

Answer (score 1):

`9 / 2` is integer division.  It evaluates to 4.

Answer (score 1):

It is done in integer mathematics (see ch. 5.6.2 in Java Language Specification) so:
9 / 2 is = 4 
then 4 * 2 is = 8
then 9 - 8 = 1

If you want 0 then do

```
public class Dec
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(9.0 - ((9.0 / 2.0) * 2.0));
    }
}
```

There is a short chapter for understanding of ["Binary Numeric conversion"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) located in Java Language specification.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing common issue of Integer division.

```
   9 - ((9 / 2) * 2)// here first 9/2=4 (int division)
```

Now `9-(4*2)=1`

That's why you are getting `1`